# google search console api - response error for the search types discover and googleNews

Tags: google-api, google-search-console

We are trying to get data from the google search console API with dimension types - web, discover, googleNews, news, image, video. They are all listed in the google API documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/webmaster-tools/v1/searchanalytics/query)

But we are getting a successful response from google API only for search types 'web', 'image', and 'news', please see it below

```
Request URL: https://www.googleapis.com/webmasters/v3/sites/sc-domain%3Amydomain.com/searchAnalytics/query?fields=responseAggregationType%2Crows



Request:
    {
      "startDate": "2022-06-05",
      "endDate": "2022-06-22",
      "dimensions": ["query","page","country"],
      "type": "web",
      "dataState": "all",
      "aggregationType": "byPage",
      "rowLimit": 5000,
      "startRow": 0
    }
 
Response:
    Queries Count: 239752

========================================================================================

Request:
{
  "startDate": "2022-06-05",
  "endDate": "2022-06-22",
  "dimensions": ["query","page","country"],
  "type": "image",
  "dataState": "all",
  "aggregationType": "byPage",
  "rowLimit": 5000,
  "startRow": 0
}
Response:
Queries Count: 1827

====================================================================================

Request:
    {
      "startDate": "2022-06-05",
      "endDate": "2022-06-22",
      "dimensions": ["query","page","country"],
      "type": "web",
      "dimensionFilterGroups": [
        {
          "groupType": "and",
          "filters": [
            {
              "dimension": "country",
              "operator": "contains",
              "expression": "GBR"
            }
          ]
        }
      ],
      "dataState": "all",
      "aggregationType": "byPage",
      "rowLimit": 5000,
      "startRow": 0
    }
    Response:
    Queries Count: 9073
```

When we are making the same request with the search type 'discover' or 'googleNews' we are getting an error in the response as below

```
Request:
{
  "startDate": "2022-06-05",
  "endDate": "2022-06-22",
  "dimensions": ["query","page","country"],
  "type": "discover",
  "dataState": "all",
  "aggregationType": "byPage",
  "rowLimit": 5000,
  "startRow": 0
}
Response:
{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Request contains an invalid argument.",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "Request contains an invalid argument.",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "badRequest"
      }
    ],
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
  }
}
```

We also have tried to make the API request for the full URL without sc-domain parameter as one below

```
https://www.googleapis.com/webmasters/v3/sites/https%3A%2F%2Fwww.mydomain.com/searchAnalytics/query?fields=responseAggregationType%2Crows
```

But still, we are getting the same errors.

My question is - what is wrong with our requests and how to get data from the google search console API for the search types 'discover' and 'googleNews'? And is there any way to get more informative error messages from google search console API responses, that will provide a bit more explanation about the reason for the error occurred?

Comment: I had same issue, removing "query" from dimensions solved the issue but not really sure why it isn't working with query as dimension